# Dynamic Nelson Siegel calibration using Kalman filter not converging

Tags: numpy, kalman-filter

I'm trying to implement a calibration code in Numpy for Dynamic Nelson Siegel model using Kalman filter. I implemented a Kalman filter (per https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1204/1204.0375.pdf) and put in the parameters following the AFNS portion of Christensen (https://www.frbsf.org/economic-research/files/wp07-20bk.pdf) except C(tau). My goal is to maximize the log likelihood of Kalman filter.

However, I'm facing an issue where the covariance of error between actual yield to maturities (Y) and expected based on the model (AX) gets very small determinant or even negative determinant, and I simply have no clue why this might be happening. I tried using different calibration methods, but they all face the same issue.

Is there something I'm missing, or is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out on my side. Thank you for answering regardless!